# Out of memory during ng build (prod build) ,angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am developing an angular app and using angular4.

while developing I got an issue with prod build
when I am developing prod build I got the below error.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I have searched for the fix and I found that need to increase the memory limit for node js as below code

```
"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
```

and it is worked fine. but I need a better solution instead of increasing the memory allocation of node js.

I am using the below configuration

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.4

node: 6.10.3

os: win32 x64

@angular/compiler: 4.4.6

@angular/core: 4.4.6

@angular/cli: 1.4.4

@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6

typescript: 2.3.4
```

Please suggest me a better solution to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Upgrade all packages to latest stable versions. @angular/cli has fixed a lot of related bugs lately.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the configuration to below and everything worked fine.

```
@angular/cli: 1.7.3
Node: 6.10.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
typescript: 2.6.2
```